# WordPress database error Regex error 'quantifier does not follow a repeatable item at offset 11'

Tags: database, security, debugging

I'm getting this error. Am I being hacked? Please take a look:

```
WordPress database error Regex error 'quantifier does not follow a repeatable item at offset 11' for query
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT wpgb_posts.ID
FROM wpgb_posts  LEFT JOIN wpgb_users users ON (wpgb_posts.post_author = users.ID)
WHERE 1=1  AND (  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Deutsche|Deutsche(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Deutsche|Deutsche(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Deutsche|Deutsche(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Deutsche|Deutsche(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Prüfungsfragen|Prüfungsfragen(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Prüfungsfragen|Prüfungsfragen(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Prüfungsfragen|Prüfungsfragen(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Prüfungsfragen|Prüfungsfragen(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Online|Online(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Online|Online(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Online|Online(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Online|Online(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Tests|Tests(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Tests|Tests(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Tests|Tests(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Tests|Tests(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Prüfungsübungen|Prüfungsübungen(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Prüfungsübungen|Prüfungsübungen(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Prüfungsübungen|Prüfungsübungen(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Prüfungsübungen|Prüfungsübungen(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Öffnen|Öffnen(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Öffnen|Öffnen(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Öffnen|Öffnen(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Öffnen|Öffnen(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Sie|Sie(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Sie|Sie(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Sie|Sie(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Sie|Sie(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])\[\[\]|\[\[\](\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])\[\[\]|\[\[\](\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])\[\[\]|\[\[\](\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])\[\[\]|\[\[\](\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])www.itzert.com|www.itzert.com(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])www.itzert.com|www.itzert.com(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])www.itzert.com|www.itzert.com(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])www.itzert.com|www.itzert.com(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])geben|geben(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])geben|geben(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])geben|geben(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])geben|geben(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Sie|Sie(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Sie|Sie(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Sie|Sie(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Sie|Sie(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])➽|➽(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])➽|➽(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])➽|➽(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])➽|➽(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])|(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])ein|ein(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])ein|ein(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])ein|ein(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])ein|ein(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])und|und(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])und|und(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])und|und(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])und|und(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])erhalten|erhalten(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])erhalten|erhalten(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])erhalten|erhalten(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])erhalten|erhalten(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Sie|Sie(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Sie|Sie(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Sie|Sie(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Sie|Sie(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])den|den(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])den|den(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])den|den(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])den|den(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])kostenlosen|kostenlosen(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])kostenlosen|kostenlosen(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])kostenlosen|kostenlosen(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])kostenlosen|kostenlosen(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Download|Download(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Download|Download(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Download|Download(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Download|Download(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])1z0-1096-22|1z0-1096-22(\[\[:\>:\]\])')) AND  ((wpgb_posts.post_title REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Deutsch|Deutsch(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_content REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Deutsch|Deutsch(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (wpgb_posts.post_excerpt REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Deutsch|Deutsch(\[\[:\>:\]\])') OR (users.display_name REGEXP '(\[\[:\<:\]\])Deutsch|Deutsch(\[\[:\>:\]\])'))) AND wpgb_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wpgb_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wpgb_posts.post_status = 'inherit'))

                    ORDER BY (CASE WHEN wpgb_posts.post_title LIKE '%1z0-1096-22 Deutsche Prüfungsfragen  1z0-1096-22 Online Tests  1z0-1096-22 Prüfungsübungen  Öffnen Sie [ www.itzert.com ] geben Sie ➽ 1z0-1096-22  ein und erhalten Sie den kostenlosen Download 1z0-1096-22 Deutsch%' THEN 1 WHEN wpgb_posts.post_title LIKE '%1z0-1096-22 Deutsche Prüfungsfragen  1z0-1096-22 Online Tests  1z0-1096-22 Prüfungsübungen  Öffnen Sie [ www.itzert.com ] geben Sie ➽ 1z0-1096-22  ein und erhalten Sie den kostenlosen Download 1z0-1096-22 Deutsch%' THEN 2 WHEN wpgb_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%1z0-1096-22 Deutsche Prüfungsfragen  1z0-1096-22 Online Tests  1z0-1096-22 Prüfungsübungen  Öffnen Sie [ www.itzert.com ] geben Sie ➽ 1z0-1096-22  ein und erhalten Sie den kostenlosen Download 1z0-1096-22 Deutsch%' THEN 4 WHEN wpgb_posts.post_content LIKE '%1z0-1096-22 Deutsche Prüfungsfragen  1z0-1096-22 Online Tests  1z0-1096-22 Prüfungsübungen  Öffnen Sie [ www.itzert.com ] geben Sie ➽ 1z0-1096-22  ein und erhalten Sie den kostenlosen Download 1z0-1096-22 Deutsch%' THEN 5 ELSE 6 END), wpgb_posts.post_date DESC
                    LIMIT 0, 10
                 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts
```

What should I do now?

I checked debug.log and found this. I'm concerned that it's an attack.